# JSF locale issue

Tags: java, jsf, localization, jsf-2

I have a situation where when a user selects a language from a drop down, I want the the application locale to change accordingly. Capturing locale is not difficult, but how to set the locale for all pages there after.

I have configuration set in resource bundles and faces-config.xml

Comment: From the docs for calculateLocale "Returns an appropriate Locale to use for this and subsequent requests for the current client." so does this means if a locale is calculated for a view and user changes locale, since locale for this view is already calculated so it will use the pre calculated and show the same view as before the locale changed ? I tested this scenario, at times calculateLocale is not called for a view if already calculated. Is Application.setDefaultLocale of any use in such a scenario.

Comment: Application.setDefaultLocale() sets default locale accross the whole Application, that is for all users. I doubt this is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Registering your own `ViewHandler` and overriding its [calculateLocale()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ViewHandler.html#calculateLocale%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method would be one way to go.

Custom `ViewHandler` needs to be indicated in `faces-config.xml` file, e.g.:

```
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns...>   
   <application>
           ...
       <view-handler>your.package.CustomLocaleViewHandler</view-handler> ...
```

And the implementation would override the `calculateLocale()` only and delegate other methods to proxied `ViewHandler`:

```
public class CustomLocaleViewHandler extends ViewHandler {

    private final ViewHandler base;

    public CustomLocaleViewHandler(ViewHandler base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    @Override
    public Locale calculateLocale(FacesContext context) {
    //... your logic goes here
    return locale;
    }

    @Override
    public String calculateRenderKitId(FacesContext context) {
        return base.calculateRenderKitId(context);
    }

    @Override
    public UIViewRoot createView(FacesContext context, String viewId) {
        return base.createView(context, viewId);
    }

    ... other proxied methods

}
```

Comment: thanks for time .... something I wont likely try to do at this stage (some restrictions cant mention..) will keep a note of it ..

Comment: From the docs for calculateLocale "Returns an appropriate Locale to use for this and subsequent requests for the current client." so does this means if a locale is calculated for a view and user changes locale, since locale for this view is already calculated so it will use the pre calculated and show the same view as before the locale changed ? I tested this scenario, at times calculateLocale is not called for a view if already calculated. Is Application.setDefaultLocale of any use in such a scenario

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.getViewRoot().setLocale(locale);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this, and it's not difficult to code, but takes a bit to figure out how to do effectively in a future-proof and automated fashion, but I *think* I have a reasonable approach that automatically detects what languages are configured in JSF, and that localizes the menu items to the current Locale automatically.

First, make sure you're using a facelets template of some sort, or you're going to have to replicate this first part on every page you use.  You set the Locale using the f:view locale= parameter

Your page(s) should look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:view locale="#{LocaleBean.currentLocale}">
        <h:head>
...
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
...
            <!-- Put this somewhere convenient on your page -->
            <h:form>
                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{Locale.currentLocale}" onchange="this.form.submit();" immediate="true" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{Locale.supportedLocales}" var="loc" itemLabel="#{loc.getDisplayName(Locale.currentLocale)}" itemValue="#{loc}"/>
                    <f:converter converterId="LocaleConverter"/>
                </h:selectOneMenu>
            </h:form>
...
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

Here's my LocaleBean:  (Register it with either @ManagedBean, or via faces-config.xml with a session scope)

```
public class LocaleBean {

    protected List<Locale> supportedLocales = new ArrayList<Locale>();

    protected Locale currentLocale;

    /**
     * Get the value of currentLocale
     *
     * @return the value of currentLocale
     */
    public Locale getCurrentLocale() {
        if (currentLocale == null && FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() != null) {
            currentLocale = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale();
        }
        return currentLocale;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of currentLocale
     *
     * @param currentLocale new value of currentLocale
     */
    public void setCurrentLocale(Locale currentLocale) {
        this.currentLocale = currentLocale;
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(currentLocale);
    }

    public List<Locale> getSupportedLocales() {
        if (supportedLocales.isEmpty() && FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() != null) {
            Iterator<Locale> facesLocales = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getSupportedLocales();
            while (facesLocales.hasNext()) {
                supportedLocales.add(facesLocales.next());
            }
        }
        return supportedLocales;
    }

    public void setSupportedLocaleStrings(Collection<String> localeStrings) {
        supportedLocales.clear();
        for (String checkLocale : localeStrings) {
            for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
                if (locale.toString().equals(checkLocale)) {
                    supportedLocales.add(locale);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

And the LocaleConverter (again, register via annotations or faces-config.xml)

```
public class LocaleConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
            if (locale.toString().equals(value)) {
                return locale;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return value.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on why you think it should look that way, instead of using JSF Converters and presenting the language selection in the current Locale? This seems to be a very low quality comment otherwise.